# Get previous date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to get the date before a given date in JavaScript. This is what I've come up with.

```
function getPreviousDay(year, month, day) {
    const date = new Date(year, month - 1, day); // the month is 0-indexed
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);

    console.log(`${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()}-${date.getDate()}`);
}

getPreviousDay(2016, 9, 30); // 2016-8-29, Expected output: 2016-9-29
getPreviousDay(2016, 10, 1); // 2016-8-30, Expected output: 2016-9-30
```

Why doesn't it work as expected? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please update to show your input as well as your desired output in your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, months, in js date object, are 0-indexed.

So you do very good to substract one from the month, when creating the date object.

Your problem is, that you don't add back that one month when **showing** the date object :

```
   console.log(`${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth() + 1}-${date.getDate()}`);
```

Comment: Thank you! The getMonth() method also returns the month in the specified date as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year).

Answer (score 1):

You make `month - 1`, when initializing the date, but should be a month.